# Location to edit xdebug.max_nesting_level in ubuntu 14.04 PHP in Lighttpd

Tags: php, python, ubuntu, xdebug, lighttpd

I am getting

```
fatal error maximum function nesting level of '100' reached aborting..
```

It seems I have to edit

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level from 100 to more.
```

But I am unable to find the correct file in where I should edit this? I am using Ubuntu 14.04 , lighttpd webserver and Php..

From internet I saw I have to edit php.ini file in /etc/php5/apache2..

But I am using lighttpd.

In my /etc/php5/ there are three folders namely

1. cgi
2. cli
3. mods-available

In the cgi and cli folder there are php.ini file, But those 2 files did not contain anyting to edit xdebug.

In mods-available folder I got 1 file namely xdebug.ini and it just contains

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
```

So I need help how to edit xdebug.max_nesting_level in ubuntu 14.04 PHP and Lighttpd. Sorry for my bad English. Seeking your help to solve this

Answer (score 1):

To fix the issue, I edited /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini and added the following line:

xdebug.max_nesting_level = 250